# Why I get error Unknown property name in css class?

Tags: html, css

I want to make  my ul li list scrollable on device.

So I have this html:

```
<div class="scrollArea ">
    <ul class="selectableListItems" ng-repeat="inspectionReview in inspectionReviews">
        <li class="row col-sm-6">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inspectionReview.IsNormal" />
            {{inspectionReview.InspectionItemName}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is css classes:

```
.selectableListItems {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.scrollArea {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    direction: ltr;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}

    .scrollArea input[type="text"] {
        border: 1px;
        direction: rtl;
    }

    .scrollArea ul {
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

That genarete this view:

[image]

But the problem that if I open it in android device the scorlling dose not work.

When I open the debugger I on chrome  I see error in scc scrollArea :

[image]

On `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property I get error `Unknown property name`.

Any idea why I get the error on `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` only works in Safari (as per [Safari's Supported CSS Properties documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)). If you're not using Safari, this property will most likely not be recognised.

I can't find any solid reference to this property in the last 3 years, so it's quite possible that even the latest versions of Safari aren't supporting it any more, either.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property is [a non-standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) and as a result it may not be recognized by all browsers.

**Current Support**

[image: enter code here]

A cursory look appears to only indicate that Safari Mobile 5+ and some earlier versions of Chrome on Android supported the property. I can't find any definitive response regarding current support.